# Show the Y-Axis line in ZedGraph

Tags: c#, winforms, zedgraph

[image]

In the picture above, there is a line for y = 0 (marking the x-axis).  There is none for x = 0 (marking the y-axis).  **How do I get one to appear at x = 0?**

I've tried...

```
MyZedGraphObject.ZedGraphControl.GraphPane.YAxis.IsVisible = true;
MyZedGraphObject.ZedGraphControl.GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.IsVisible = true;
```

Neither seem to work.  The color for the y axis is black, so it's not a fully transparent color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `YAxis.Cross` property to the desired `X` value. For example, the following code:

```
MyZedGraphObject.ZedGraphControl.GraphPane.AddCurve(
    null, new[] { -0.3, 0.5, 0.9 }, new[] { 0.8, 0.3, 0.1 }, Color.Blue);

MyZedGraphObject.ZedGraphControl.GraphPane.YAxis.Cross = 0.0;
MyZedGraphObject.ZedGraphControl.GraphPane.AxisChange();
```

would yield the following graph:

[image: Y axis cross at X = 0]